# I can't figure out why complex valued function of one complex variable admit non-zero derivatives and need help to confute my wrong proof .

Tags: complex-analysis

A complex-valued function has a real part and an imaginary part. Thus every complex-valued function of a complex variable $f$ can be written as:$$f(z) =u(z) +iv(z)$$
where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued functions of a complex variable. It follows that a complex-valued function $f$ of a complex variable is really the same as a pair of real-valued functions $(u,v)$ of a complex variable.

Now, we know that real-valued functions of complex variable always have null derivative, so I am tempted to write:$$f'(z)=u'(z)+iv'(z)=0.$$
This is obviously wrong but I need to understand why. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Now, we know that real-valued functions of complex variable always have null derivative" I think you should look into this statement and see exactly what it actually says.

Comment: They have null derivative *when they have one* (in the sense of complex derivative), i.e. when they are holomorphic. Test your "proof" on $f(z)=z,$ i.e. $u=\Re,v=\Im.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. So what you are trying to say is that it is not true that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic then $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ are necessarely holomorphic... I figured it out with that example, but to me it is kind of strange. I mean you can write a holomorphic function as the sum of two non holomorphic functions... How can this be?

Comment: Well thinking a little more about it, expressing a limit that exists as the sum of two limit that do not exist separately is possible so i think this makes sense now. Can we say that i only proved that if you can express $f$ as $u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are differentiable, then $f'(z)=0$ ?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic and non-constant, then $u$ and $v$ are necessary non-holomorphic (they take only real values by definition, and non-constant holomorphic function takes non-real values on any open set). But I also don't understand what do you men by "real-valued functions of complex variable always have null derivative".

Comment: Thanks, these are enlightening results i didn't know about.

Comment: In my question i referred to the following statement from Ahlfors' Complex analysis: "Let $f(z)$ be a real function of a complex variable whose derivative exists at $z = a$. Then $f'(a)$ is on one side real, for it is the limit of the quotients $(f(a + h)-f(a))/h$ as $h$ tends to zero through real values. On the other side it is also the limit of the quotients $(f(a + ih) -f(a))/ih$ and as such purely imaginary. Therefore $f'(a)$ must be zero. Thus a real function of a  complex variable either has the derivative zero, or else the derivative does not exist."

Comment: You should write out what you think the co-domains are for $\big\{f, u, v\big\}$ and decide based on co-domain, which functions that passage from Alhfors applies to